# How to change 'overlayOpacity' just for one step with intro.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

I want to change the 'overlayOpacity' option to 0.5 for only one specific step. How can I realize this functionality and change that parameter back to the default value?

Examples, which do not work:

```js
introJs().step2().setOption("overlayOpacity", 0.5);

if(introJs().step2()){
  introJs().setOption("overlayOpacity", 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API documentation of intro.js](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/callbacks/onbeforechange.html) is not super clear, but I found one example in the repository, that might give you an idea how to solve your problem:

1. Listen for the step changes
2. Check for `_currentStep` equals the desired step

```js
introJs().onbeforechange(function() {
  if (this._currentStep === 1) {
    introJs().setOption("overlayOpacity", 0.5);
  } else {
    introJs().setOption("overlayOpacity", 0.8);
  }
});
```

**Note:** [The default parameter of `overlayOpacity` is 0.8](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/d3059b0edd8ca7d020fe9d25ed6835f694ebae6f/intro.js#L90) and should be changed back, if the user left the desired step. And keep in mind, that this listener fires the callback function *before* the step change. Therefore we need `currentStep === 1`, instead of 2.

Comment: it doesn't work for me 'introJs().setOption()' I think it only works in the latest version. But i used  '$("#introjs-helperLayer").css("background-color","rgba(255,255,255,0.5)")' and it worked. But you helped take the step, I'll give up vote. thanks

Comment: Which version are you using? Maybe add this information to your question. Then I could check that specific version of introjs for how to set an option.

Comment: i use version "v2.9.3", and not work! Is weird. in this version the overlayOpacity default is 0.9

Comment: refering to [this](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/1414#issuecomment-962427013), it would not possible to change the options during runtime.